# Hiding empty table column when empty

Tags: tables, longtable, longtabu

I have tables (tabu, longtable and other) generated with PHP with variable cell content. Sometimes, all cells in column are empty, and in that case I would to hide whole column with header.

[Here](http://texblog.org/2014/10/24/removinghiding-a-column-in-a-latex-table/) we have solution to manually hide column. Is it possible to write any script that does it automatically?

**Minimal example code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\hline
\textbf{Lp.} & name \\\hline 
 1 &  \\\hline
 2 &  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In this case, I want to hide the "name" column

Comment: Perhaps show example code with sample data, to work on.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz - i added minimal example. In this case i need to render table with only first column.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: what is the problem with the solution you cite i find it good.

Comment: It looks easier to me to do this kind of stuff on the generator (PHP) side. Doing this on the LaTeX side seems wrong because it assumes LaTeX understands the meaning of the columns. For example, you use a divider (`|`) in the required argument of `longtable`. It's not clear whether it should be kept when a column becomes empty or not.

Comment: Hi, i've edited my minimal example to be compilable. I also removed `|` so it won't bother you. Please tell me if it's possible to make conditions under which column is not visible (if rows 2-last are empty -> hide column)

Comment: how can latex know the 2nd column is empty? especially in the long table case that isn't known until the end of the table by which time the earlier parts have been shipped out and aren't even in memory any more.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: One could put (tikz)marks at the begin and end of every data cell and then measure the distance between both, it is is zero for all cells the column is empty. But this looks like a lot of trouble for something that should be easy for find out on the php-side.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Or longtable measures the widths anyway but the cells are forced wide by the heading. Yes it's possible (I probably wouldn't use tikz:-) but massively complicated compared to just inputting the required document:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://texblog.org/2014/10/24/removinghiding-a-column-in-a-latex-table/) and [this page](http://tex-and-stuff.blogspot.com/2011/03/counting-number-of-characters-in-tex_10.html), here's a crude answer which can be further improved:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
% define hidden column type
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
% counter for non-blanks
\newcounter{ub}
% define character count function
\def\gchar{\let\char= }
\newcount\ccount
\def\cunil{%
  \ifx\char\nil \let\next=\relax%
  \else%
    \let\next=\axchar%
    \advance\ccount by 1%
  \fi\next
}
\def\axchar{\afterassignment\cunil\gchar}
\def\cchar#1{\edef\xx{#1}\ccount=0 \expandafter\axchar\xx\nil}
\long\def\xc#1{#1\cchar{#1}
\ifnum\ccount>0
\stepcounter{ub}
\fi
}
% define conditional display function
\def\disptab#1{
\ifnum#1>0%
   \tablebody{c c}%
\else%
   \tablebody{c H}%
\fi
}
% define table structure function
\def\tablebody#1{
\begin{tabular}{#1}
\hline
\textbf{Lp.} & name \\\hline 
%%%%%% try removing what is in \xc{} %%%%%%
 1 & \xc{} \\\hline
 2 & \xc{abc} \\\hline
 3 & \xc{} \\\hline
 4 & \xc{3.14} \\\hline
 5 & \xc{} \\\hline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

% use box to initially render table without displaying it,
% so non-blanks can be counted
\newbox\uvox
\setbox\uvox\hbox{\tablebody{c c}}

% display table
\disptab{\theub}
\end{document}
```

Note that each cell in the column to hide should be enclosed with `\xc{}` in order for this to work.